# imageView doesn't appear in emulator

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following code , but it only show the correct result in android studio not in the emulator , I have using nexus 5 as my emulator , I tried wrap_content and fill_parent in imageView and it doesn't work also

[`this is the compilation result`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfWWY.png) `

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/androidparty"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/happy_birthday_to_you"
        android:textColor="#ED0707"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/abdo"
        android:textColor="#E61212"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Which exact class does `MainActivity` extend?

Comment: It extends Activity Class

Comment: That's your problem. The `app:srcCompat` attribute belongs to `AppCompatImageView`, and an `<ImageView>` tag will only be automatically substituted with an `AppCompatImageView` in an `AppCompatActivity`. You're apparently set up to use the support/androidx libraries; otherwise, that attribute is unlikely to resolve. Is there any particular reason you're extending plain `Activity` there instead of  `AppCompatActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- Making activity extend `AppCompatActivity`

OR

- `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`